# Slide toggle element when height is dynamic

Tags: jquery

I'm showing a comment section when pressing an arrow, like in the picture below. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVsgH/32/) as well.

Two parts should slide toggle here, the info text section and the comment section.

The problem is that the top square doesn't slide toggle when it shows (from height 60px to height 100%). It does however slide when it hides (from 100% to 60px).

I want it to slide when it shows but can't figure it out. My guess is that it doesn't slide because the height is dynamic (100%) and that jQuery needs a specific target height in pixel to animate?

```
$("footer").on("tap click", function () {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
    var section = $(this).prev();
    section.height() == 60 ? 
       section.height("100%") : 
       section.animate({ height: "60"}, "fast");
});
```

[image]

Comment: www.jsfiddle.net <- please make a fiddle to show your code

Comment: wooops sorry, didn't see it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("footer").on("tap click", function () {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
    var section = $(this).prev(),
        toHeight = (section.height() == 60) ? section.get(0).scrollHeight : 60;
    section.animate({ height: toHeight}, "fast");
});
```

Comment: This works great, but do you know if this is compatible with smartphones and all standard browsers as well?

Comment: @Niklas, I did not check, but it must, ".scrollHeight" is pure JS property.